# Cypress click on set of elements but not loop forever

Tags: javascript, for-loop, cypress

I have a few places that I need to click on a number of elements but I don't want it to loop through. I feel that the answer is right in front of me, but cant find the right solution.

Here is one code example which right now is stuck in a forever loop:

```
for(let n = 1; n <= 19; n++){
        cy.get('li.active > .nav > :nth-child(n) > a').click({multiple: true})
        cy.wait(400)
    }
```

I have 19 elements all of which are the same just numbered 1-19 and I just want the test to click on them, wait to let it show the page, then click the next one.

---

**Answer**

```
            cy.get('#side-menu > :nth-child(2) > a').click()
        cy.wait(400)
        cy.get('li.active > .nav').each(($ele) => {
  cy.wrap($ele).find('a').click({multiple:true})
})
```

Also took care of my other for loop that went on for forever and never stopped unless manually stopped like this original issue by replacing it with `each()` as well.

````
    cy.get('#side-menu > li > a').each(($ele) => {
        cy.wrap($ele).click({multiple:true})
        })
    ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `each()` loop to iterate through your elements and click on the buttons one by one -

```js
cy.get('li.active > .nav').each(($ele) = > {
  cy.wrap($ele).find('a').click()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If your page refreshes each click, you cannot use Cypress `.each()` because you will get "detached from DOM" error.

Try a recursive function

```js
it('tests the nav buttons', () => {

  function clickNav(buttonNum) {
    if (buttonNum === 20) return   // finished
    cy.get('li.active > .nav > :nth-child(n) > a').click()
    cy.wait(400)
    clickNav(++buttonNum)   // next
  }

  clickNav(1)
})
```

But something else is going on, technically your loop should also work.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the solutions - Alpan's worked as such:

```
            cy.get('#side-menu > :nth-child(2) > a').click()
        cy.wait(400)
        cy.get('li.active > .nav').each(($ele) => {
  cy.wrap($ele).find('a').click({multiple:true})
})
```

Forgot I had to open the drop down via the nth-child click then added the `{multiple:true}` inside of click in the `each()`